# Keep track of people I unfollow on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to keep track of people I unfollow on Twitter.

I regularly look for Twitter users that might be interested in my Twitter accounts (I use specific keywords to find users and so on). But I have no interest in following them (well at least most of them). It's just a way to say "hey! Look at this!".

I would like to keep a track of the accounts I unfollow so I don't follow them again (I don't want to spam them).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a (private) list of people you follow and each time you find an interesting account you add them to the list and follow them, if that account is already on that list it means you have already follow/unfollow(ed) them.